# Animation isn't stopping when animation.stop() and reset() is called

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an Animation on my Chronometer and it works well when I start it. I'm starting it like this:

```
chTimer.stop();
chTimer.startAnimation(animBlink);
```

Then I'm trying to cancel the animation like this:

```
chTimer.start();
animBlink.cancel();
animBlink.reset();
```

The animation isn't stopping no matter what. It just keeps playing (blinking) even though cancel() and reset() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stopping *Animation* for whatever `View` you should use this:

```
chTimer.clearAnimation();
chTimer.setAnimation(null);
```

and it should works<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>I'm using this approach in my project(s) and never had a problems with this issue.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Things like this should be documented in a way to be easily accessible. I googled "stopping android animation" in a hundred different ways and a solution like this never popped up.